# Writing a program which can open and use another program: (Audio program)

Tags: c++, windows, macos, audio, reaper

I've got a project going on, far away from complete, a stand alone audio mixer/effects processor.  I plan to eventually, have all of my effects in stand alone program as VST, AU, and maybe TDM plugins.

I would like to be able to batch convert all the files in a project using an external sample rate converter.  If not your choice of external converter, then just a specific program, R8 "brain free", or "R8 brain" pro, by Voxengo.

The second thing I would like to be able to do, is launch "Reaper", from within a project in my program, and have the files in a project, opened in reaper, and all of my effects plugins added with specific settings.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: I never heard of such programs, but what OS are you targeting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what level of automation interface the other programs offer.  This could range from taking command line parameters to perform certain actions, to offering a sophisticated automation interface through a mechanism such as COM or OLE automation.  It's a matter of checking what is offered by the software you plan to run from your own program.

The [reaper documentation](http://wiki.cockos.com/wiki/index.php/REAPER_API) suggests it has quite a good API for automation purposes.